# Excel Write cell if another cell has a 1

Tags: google-sheets

I have done some digging and I haven't found the solution to my problem. To be honest I don't know the "keywords' to search to find the solution to this problem.

I have a list of names in a in one sheet2.

I want to scan a column with that person's name at the top in sheet1. every time the number "1" appears in that column I want to write the text (Course name) from that row. The number 1 will appear up to 7 times.

I have tried vertical lookup and if statements but not getting what I need.

A picture is worth a thousand words I guess.[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQMgw.png) [Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAwBZ.png)

Comment: Are you looking for things like `FILTER()` and `TEXTJOIN()` for example? Hard to tell when you don't include your desired results. Also, it appears that you are actually working with GS and **not** Excel. You may want to edit your title and tags.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet for extra fast answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming your data are in the cells below on *Sheet1* (it's impossible to be sure between your having merged cells, and no row labels visible):
[image: rendering of OP's Sheet1]

I believe this is what you want for *Sheet2*:
[image: rendering of OP's Sheet2]

The formula in cells `C2:C6` of *Sheet2* is

```
=TRANSPOSE(filter(Sheet1!$B$8:$B$16,INDEX(Sheet1!$I$8:$K$16,,MATCH(B2,Sheet1!$I$4:$K$4,0))))
```

The formula below

```
=filter(B8:B16,I8:I16)
```

*if* entered on Sheet1 would result in a vertical range comprising *BIOLOGIE 11*, and *BUSINESS TECHNOLOGY 11*, i.e. entries from `B8:B16` where the rows have a 1 in the `I8:I16` range.
Since there are several students, the `I8:I16` range must be determined dynamically; this is why the [INDEX()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en) and [MATCH()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en) functions are used.
The INDEX() function is used to a return a component of the range used as it's first argument, i.e. part of the `Sheet1!$I$8:$K$16` range, as that is where the 1s/blanks for the 3 (visible) students reside (you will have to widen it for your actual data).

The INDEX() function can take 2 additional arguments, being the row number and column number of the cell (within `Sheet1!$I$8:$K$16`) that we want returned. While both of these arguments can be supplied, only one is mandatory - in this context, the row argument is skipped, and only a value for the column is supplied: this means that the component of `Sheet1!$I$8:$K$16` that we want return is an entire column (i.e. all the rows for that column).

The MATCH() function is what is used to determine the column, i.e. it identifies the position, of the current student's name, within the `Sheet1!$I$4:$K$4` range (the 3rd argument, 0, to the MATCH() function means that we want an exact match; again you will have to widen this range for your actual data).
In this way the INDEX() and MATCH() functions combined identify the column of 1s/blanks appropriate to the current student; this then forms the second argument to the [FILTER()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) function, so that it can return the subjects appropriate to the current student.

Finally, the [TRANSPOSE()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en) function is used because you want the results populated horizontally whereas, by default, the FILTER() function returns a vertical range.